# Custom horizontal scroll bar does not go to the end of the track

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I have created a custom scroll bar for the jscrollpane which appears to be working fine until I scroll to the end and it stops just before the end like its stuck. I want it to go to the end so people know that there is no more to scroll. The only css styles that i have changed are jspHorizontalBar, jspTrack, jspDrag.

```
/*
* CSS Styles that are needed by jScrollPane for it to operate correctly.
*
* Include this stylesheet in your site or copy and paste the styles below into your stylesheet - jScrollPane
* may not operate correctly without them.
*/

.jspContainer
{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
position: absolute;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 16px;
height: 100%;
background: red;
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background-color: #fff;
}

.jspVerticalBar *,
.jspHorizontalBar *
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.jspCap
{
display: none;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap
{
float: left;
}

.jspTrack
{
background: #fff;
position: relative;
background-image:url(../images/track.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


.jspDrag
{
position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
background-image:url(../images/move_me.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: 0px;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
.jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspArrow
{
background: #50506d;
text-indent: -20000px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
cursor: default;
background: #80808d;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
height: 16px;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow
{
width: 16px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow:focus
{
outline: none;
}

.jspCorner
{
background: #eeeef4;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

/* Yuk! CSS Hack for IE6 3 pixel bug :( */
* html .jspCorner
{
margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix.

You have ->

```
<div class="jspDrag" style="width: 166px; left: 1097px;">
```

The width of this object is hitting the end of the page. Change the width and the object will be allowed to go to the end of the page.

Comment: When I use firebug to inspect the element it is telling me that jspDrag and .jspDrag .jspHover and .jspDrag .jspActive classes have a width of 420px but when I add this in to the jScrollPane Css styles nothing changes - what am I missing?  thanks

Comment: Sorry for not responding in a quicker fashion. While you may have set the CSS of the object in your .CSS file. When I look at the Element, it has an INLINE width. That means something is setting the width of the element, either JavaScript, PHP, or it's written INTO the element in the HTML file.